# Python pattern negative look behind

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to figure out a regex pattern that matches a file path string in which a file called "cmd.exe" is NOT located in the "System32" folder OR any subfolder of it.

The Pattern should match on this:

```
C:\Tools\calc.exe
```

But not on this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\System32\De-de\calc.exe
```

I tried a negative look behind:

```
(?<![Ss]ystem32)\\calc\.exe
(?<![Ss]ystem32).*\\calc\.exe
(?<![Ss]ystem32[.*])\\calc\.exe
```

But nothing worked so far. 
Does anyone see my error?

You can see my example and try it out yourself here:
http://rubular.com/r/syAoEn7xxx

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can just search if `\System32\\` is substring of your target string. if yes, invalid. not found? ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the regex aspect of the question, the problem is that `re` doesn't support lookbehinds of variable length:

```
rx = r'(?<!System32.*)calc.exe'
re.search(rx, r'C:\Tools\calc.exe')

> sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

There are two workarounds:

install and use the newer [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module that does support that (and much, much more):

```
rx = r'(?<!System32.*)calc.exe'
print regex.search(rx, r'C:\Tools\calc.exe')  # <_regex.Match object at 0x1028dd238>
print regex.search(rx, r'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe') # None
```

or rephrase the expression so that it doesn't require a variable lookbehind:

```
rx = r'^(?!.*System32).*calc.exe'
print re.search(rx, r'C:\Tools\calc.exe')  # <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10aede238>
print re.search(rx, r'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe') # None
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use functions from `os.path`-module when working with filenames.

I'd propose:

```
from os.path import basename, dirname

paths = [r"C:\Tools\calc.exe",
         r"C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe",
         r"C:\Windows\System32\De-de\calc.exe"]

good_paths = [p for p in paths if basename(p).lower() == "calc.exe"
                               and not "system32" in dirname(p).lower()]
```

The core is the list comprehension over `paths`, checking on the `basename` (the last part of the path) and `dirname`, the name of the containing directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex.

```
def iter_good_paths(list_of_paths):
    for path in list_of_paths:
        parts = path.lower().split(r'\')
        if parts[-1] == 'calc.exe' and 'System32' in parts:
            yield path
```

and use it like:

```
print list(iter_good_paths(list_of_paths))
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a look-behind here, let alone a variable width one. Use a look-ahead instead:

```
(?i)^(?:(?!\\System32\\).)*\\calc\.exe$
```

This will match anything that doesn't contain the case insensitive string `\system32\` before your desired  `\calc.exe` string. The `(?i)` part of the expression makes everthing to the right of it case insensitive (which is probably a good bet if this is for a windows file system).

I would love to recommend [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). It is an excellent resource for learning regex in many of their quirks and flavors.